# Elastic Search: Query on newly added field

Tags: elasticsearch

I've added a new field in database (suppose `vendor_id`, with default value `0`). So this field is not  indexed in previously added item in Elasticsearch. But now I have to perform query based on this key. So,

1. If user search with `vendor_id`=n (n>0), it should search that it has the  key `vendor_id`, and it's value is equal to n.
2. If user search with `vendor_id`=0, it should search that it does not have  the  key `vendor_id`, or if the `vendor_id` key is present, than it's value is equal to 0.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "vendor_id":n
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit research on [Boolean Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) I found a solution of the issue.

1. If user search with vendor_id=n (n>0), it should search that it has the key vendor_id, and it's value is equal to n.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "vendor_id":n
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. If user search with vendor_id=0, it should search that it does not have the key vendor_id, or if the vendor_id key is present, than it's value is equal to 0.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "vendor_id":0
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "vendor_id"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`exists` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) to test for the existence of a value in a field.

You will probably have to implement some logic of your requirements in the code generating the elasticsearch query (i.e., case 1 and 2 are different elasticsearch queries).